# create a dynamic array of object, delete object and free memory in C++

Tags: c++

Hello everybody ! I am a beginner in C++ so I don't really have a good experience.

I want some help,

I try to create a dynamic array of object `(type ELEMENT)`, I have a problem when I want to delete an object from array (Error 2157)

This is a part of code :

```
class ELEMENT
{
private :
     int id_num;
     int nbnr;
     int BI;
public :
: void () ................
: ...............
:  
 };

 ELEMENT *T;   

/* before calling the next fonction, I allocate a dynamic memory space every time for T by
 T = new TAB;  because I don't know the exact size of T, I don't know if it's right like this ?
*/

void eval (int nr, int BS)
{

for (int i=0; i< size; i++)
{if (T [i].BI >= BS)
delete T [i];   // I try to delete the object in position (i) and also free allocated memory
// before I tried with delete [] T; doesn't work !
}

}
```

and the other question, is there any function to get the current size of `T`.
I tried with `SizeOf(T)` doesn't give right value.

That's all, thanks for your answers !

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754864/c-how-to-free-memory-of-dynamic-struct-array?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

You need to decide on the size of your array and then allocate dynamically as

```
T = new ELEMENT[size];
```

This creates an array of ELEMENT items which you delete once with

```
delete [] T;
```

You should not call delete on each element of T. The only time you would need this would be if T contained pointers to dynamically allocated memory (which they do not in your case) so do not do this.

There is no way to get the size of T using a dynamically allocated array. However, if you were to use `std::vector` instead you would be able to do this and also not have to worry about memory allocation and release at all.

Comment: I would not say 'You do not need to call delete on each element of T.' but 'You can't delete the element of T individually'

Comment: Thank's for your answer; So with this structure I can't point to an element (specific position) of array and delete it, that's what you mean ?

Comment: @user3334513 You allocate memory for an array - this is a contiguous block and within this memory region will be the space for each ELEMENT of your array. When you delete the array using `delete [] T` you are freeing all of the memory - there is no need to do anything else. You should never call delete on the elements of your array **unless they are pointers to memory that you have allocated elsewhere**.  I strongly suggest that once you have understood the correct usage of  `new` and `delete` that you look at std::vector which will relieve you of the need for memory management of this kind.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can't delete one element from an array and free the memory. You can only delete the while array by `delete[]`.

Secondly, you define `T` as a pointer of `ELEMENT`, so `sizeof()` will return the pointer size but not the array's size. You can remember the size by yourself, or define `T` as an array such as `ELEMENT T[10]`.

Answer (score -1):

With statement ELEMENT *T you have created a pointer to an object of class ELEMENT, but that pointer is not currently initialized ( it is not pointing to any object ). Use

```
ELEMENT *T = new ELEMENT;
```

to initialize the pointer to an object.

For the size of an array you can use

```
sizeof(nameOfYourArray)/sizeof(nameOfYourArray[0])
```

which calculates the size of an array by dividing total number of bytes with the number of bytes occupied by the first element.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually the `sizeof` code will *not* work. Try it yourself and think about what it’s supposed to do. And `new`, while it works, is very bad advice, and doesn’t answer OP’s question.